# Compare arrays across tables

Tags: sql, presto

I'm querying some **`data (SQL, presto)`**, I'm struggling to join 2 tables. I need to know which teams the issues are associated with based on the team tags set out in the tags table. Each issue could be associated with numerous teams.

Table 1 `team`:

```
name  | tags
------+--------------------
team1 | [1234, 2345, 5678]
team2 | [6789, 4321]
team3 | [4530]
team4 | [6532]
team5 | [3452, 34234, 868686]
```

Table 2 `issues`:

```
issue_id | tags
---------+--------------------------------------------
   1     | [312312, 45345, 4535,1111,4533,4530, 4321 ]
   2     | [312312, 45345, 6532]
   3     | [6532]
   4     | [312312, 1234, 4321]
   5     | [312312]
```

I need it to look like:

```
issue_id | team
---------+--------
1        | team3
1        | team2
2        | team4
3        | team4
4        | team1
4        | team2
```

I'd like to avoid hardcoding as the list of `teams` and their associated `tags` can be dynamic, but not sure how to approach this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL below explodes the value of tags in both tables to convert from array to single values so that they can be joined across 2 tables to query and display teams & their corresponding issues.

```
  Select T2.issue_id as issue_id,
             T1.name as team
  from
   (SELECT name, tag
    FROM table1
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS t (tag)) T1
   JOIN
  (SELECT issue_id, tag
    FROM table2
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS t (tag)) T2
  ON T1.tag = T2.tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed your example in Snowflake which has `flatten` function. From what I see in presto's doc it does have it as well. Maybe that will help?

In Snowflake I've managed to get your requirement.

```
with ISSUES as(

SELECT 
    T.ISSUE_ID,
    X.VALUE::INTEGER AS TAGS
FROM PUBLIC.ISSUES T, LATERAL FLATTEN(T.TAGS) X),

TEAMS as(
SELECT 
    T.TEAM,
    X.VALUE::INTEGER AS TAGS
FROM PUBLIC.TEAMS T, LATERAL FLATTEN(T.TAGS) X)


SELECT 
   ISSUES.ISSUE_ID, 
   TEAMS.TEAM FROM TEAMS
INNER JOIN ISSUES on TEAMS.TAGS = ISSUES.TAGS
```

Comment: Thanks! It does have flatten but LATERAL doesn't seem to be work in the version I'm using. Your method helped me to figure it out though!

Comment: Good to hear. No problem!